# Eval() freeze for large exponents

Tags: python, time, eval, freeze, exponentiation

I've been making a genetic program and I've come across a problem. It seems that it will try to calculate large exponents but freeze (which is understandable, because it is a large number) in the process. Is there any way to time the execution? This way I could stop calculating before it freezes for several minutes. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I have a great idea: Don't use `eval`!!

Comment: use [Threads](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-threadingpython/) for heavy computational work.

Comment: `eval` is bad stuff.. Also, you need to show us some code to find what's wrong with it.

Comment: @clcto: No, not in Python, especially CPython. In CPython, if you have more than one CPU-bound thread, they just get in each other's way. (And before 3.2, even having _one_ CPU-bound thread gets in the way of other threads.) So you should use _processes_ for heavy computational work, not threads. (And it's often not a bad idea in other languages; it avoids many of the painful race problems that plague multithreaded programs.)

Comment: What should function or process I use instead of eval() and multiprocessing for calculating the value of strings while timing them to make sure they don't take hours? An example would be eval("85*85940385034").

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you don't really want to do what you're asking. (In fact, there's more than one red flag there.) But if you do:

The only way you can let something run, while also timing is, is to put it in a separate thread or process.

If you want to be able to forcibly interrupt that something, it has to be a process.

So, for example:

```
import multiprocessing

def try_slow_thing(function, args, timeout):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=function, args=args)
    p.start()
    p.join(timeout)
    if p.is_alive():
        p.terminate()
        raise TimeoutError("stupid process wouldn't finish")
```

If you want to return a value from the function, or share values from the main process, or anything else more fancy than just "run and finish or don't", read the introductory parts of the [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) docs and skim the rest. (In fact, do that anyway.)